# Electron BrowserWindow application icon cached on Windows by App ID

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm updating an Electron app and the Taskbar icon is set in main.js as follows:

```
const iconPath = path.join(__dirname, '../resources/myicon.ico');

/** Create the browser window. */
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    resizable: IS_DEV,
    height: 650,
    minHeight: 650,
    width: 900,
    minWidth: 900,
    frame: false, // enable window chrome
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    },
    icon: iconPath,
    show: false // don't show immediately,
});
```

myicon.ico has been updated after a rebrand of the application, but the old icon is still appearing in the taskbar!

However, I notice if I change the App ID:

```
import { app } from 'electron';
app.setAppUserModelId('com.mycompany.myapp-NEW');
```

The icon now updates & appears correctly!

I'm guessing there's some Windows-level caching of icons based on Application ID. However if we publish this update I cannot get all the users to refresh icon caches or uninstall-reinstall the app.

Is there a way to force through an icon change and override the caching? May not be specific to Electron but seems [others have encountered this problem](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/issues/557).

Answer (score 0):

Hah - after 24 hours battling with this I found the problem

The same app was installed on my PC as a release and I'm working on a development version locally

Uninstalling the app meant the local version no longer conflicted and picked up the correct, newer icon